# ¿Puedo modificar algún archivo phtml sin borrar la cache?

Tags: php, cache, magento2

Siempre que quiero editar algún archivo phtml de magento, después tengo que borrar la cache de toda la web. ¿Hay alguna forma de no tener que borrar la cache o de borrar la cache específica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El sistema de Caché de Magento siempre ha sido la mayor "pesadilla" para los que trabajamos con dicha herramienta.

En Magento 2 el sistema mejoró un poco con los "Magento mode", pero aún así se requiere un poco de paciencia y experiencia para entender y ajustarse al sistema de Caché.

---

Respondiendo a las preguntas:

1. Para no borrar la caché cada vez que se hace una modificación, es necesario trabajar en modo "developer", y tener abierto siempre el devTools de Chrome (y obviamente desactivar la caché de este último también). Hay quienes prefieren trabajar con todas las cachés desactivadas, lo cual puede hacer el proceso de desarrollo y testeo bastante lento, pero generalmente es lo que mejor funciona para ver las modificaciones hechas a nivel de templates "de inmediato.

   Según Magento también es posible lograr estos efectos teniendo la caché activada gracias a la complejidad y "potencia" de su sistema, pero no puedo dar fe 100% de ello, pareciera que a veces funciona y a veces no.

   Debes tener en cuenta antes de iniciar tu "día de desarrollo" que Magento tiene varias caché y compilaciones y lo mejor es garantizar que estén "limpias" antes de iniciar el día, para evitarnos fuertes dolores de cabeza: Redis, memcached, archivos, compilación de assets, precompilación de los mismos, Dependency Injection, entre otras.
2. Hasta donde conozco no es posible eliminar una caché específica para un template, al menos no con las herramientas que Magento trae por defecto.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: A ver si soy capaz de trabajar en el modo production, porque la web ya esta publicada y hay que hacerle cambios constantemente. También tengo bloques dinámicos y se actualizan cuando quieren. Muchas gracias

Comment: En el modo production no debes hacer ninguna modificación

Comment: Es una pésima práctica en cualquier proyecto, ¿no tienes un ambiente de desarrollo al menos local y un sistema de deploy? Es lo mínimo que debería tener todo proyecto.  Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Si si tengo un ambiente de desarrollo, pero a la hora de hacer los cambios a la web publicada, al borrar la cache para ver los cambios, bajaría mucho la velocidad de la web y eso no nos lo podemos permitir como práctica constante, ya que de normal hay mucha gente en ella. Por otro lado, el entorno de desarrollo lo utilizamos para probar cambios más grandes. Voy a seguir investigando. Ojalá encontremos alguna manera de hacerlo eficientemente. Un saludo

Comment: He liderado proyectos muy grandes en Magento y lo que hacemos es "calentar" la caché cada vez que se hace un deploy.  Magento 2 no está diseñado para hacer modificaciones ni deploys a producción cada 5 minutos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo. No puedo darte más uno a la puntuación aún, no tengo los requisitos que me dice la página sorry, soy relativamente nuevo en stack overflow

Comment: Puedes marcarla como aceptada entonces, en el ícono de aprobación que aparece al lado izquierdo, debajo del cero.